# Customizing Adobe's React Spectrum Theme

Tags: reactjs, adobe, spectrumjs

Recently I was playing with the React Spectrum design system from Adobe. The website wide theme feature provided by them is great. But I feel the dark theme is not dark enough. Is there a way to customize the out of the box theme in Adobe's React Spectrum?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some info about theming from the docs.
https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-spectrum/theming.html

Comment: Cool, but the docs don't give you an example of how you actually do it